# c# HttpClient with https gets 400 Bad Request - but http works

Tags: c#, http, https

I'm trying to get a web request working using HttpClient.  It works when using http, but does not work with https.  The URL I'm testing with works in a browser with both http and https, however, when using the code below it works only with http.

One of the URLs I test with is one I setup with both http and https.  This code has the same problem there as well.

Do I need to add another confuration to make HttpClient work with https?

Note:  I have used the proxy below in a Python app and it works for both http and https so the problem is not the proxy.

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var url = "https://www.google.com";
    using (System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(@"http://38.39.202.55:80"),
        UseProxy = true,
    })
    {
        using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient hc = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler))
        {
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
            string data = "";
            using (System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await hc.GetAsync(url))
            {
                data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                System.Console.WriteLine(data);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: _"The URL I'm testing with works in a browser with both http and https"_ - is that too with a _proxy?_

Comment: I think there are is a cookie that is causing confusion.  What you posted is not consistent.  So I recommend repeating your test and between each test go into a browser and manually delete all cookies.

Comment: OK my browser comment was confusing.  What I meant by that is some websites accept only http or https.  the browser test was to verify that the website runs on both meaning that the c# code above should work.

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with the verification of ssl certificates. Thus, for example, you could edit the web.config file to bypass ssl errors. Like this:

```
     <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: You could also write methods that does the same thing. :)

Comment: This is a console app so I added the config data into the app.config directly below <configuration> and it did not work.  Same result.